# Create a named Range using an Array in Google Sheets or Alternatives in Appscript

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, countif

I have a few array ranges that I'm using in a `COUNTIF` to get the stats I need.
Although it works very well it is very long and inefficient.

Here is what it looks like:

```
=COUNTIFS(
  { Contacts!$S$3:$S, Contacts!$AA$3:$AA, Contacts!$AI$3:$AI, Contacts!$AQ$3:$AQ,Contacts!$AY$3:$AY,Contacts!$BG$3:$BG,Contacts!$BO$3:$BO,Contacts!$BW$3:$BW,Contacts!$CE$3:$CE,Contacts!$CM$3:$CM,Contacts!$CU$3:$CU,Contacts!$DC$3:$DC,Contacts!$DK$3:$DK,Contacts!$DS$3:$DS,Contacts!$EA$3:$EA,Contacts!$EI$3:$EI,Contacts!$EQ$3:$EQ,Contacts!$EY$3:$EY,Contacts!$FG$3:$FG,Contacts!$FO$3:$FO }, 
  2,
  { Contacts!$R$3:$R,Contacts!$Z$3:$Z,Contacts!$AH$3:$AH,Contacts!$AP$3:$AP,Contacts!$AX$3:$AX,Contacts!$BF$3:$BF,Contacts!$BN$3:$BN,Contacts!$BV$3:$BV,Contacts!$CD$3:$CD,Contacts!$CL$3:$CL,Contacts!$CT$3:$CT,Contacts!$DB$3:$DB,Contacts!$DJ$3:$DJ,Contacts!$DR$3:$DR,Contacts!$DZ$3:$DZ,Contacts!$EH$3:$EH,Contacts!$EP$3:$EP,Contacts!$EX$3:$EX,Contacts!$FF$3:$FF,Contacts!$FN$3:$FN }, 
  $A19,
  { Contacts!$T$3:$T,Contacts!$AB$3:$AB,Contacts!$AJ$3:$AJ,Contacts!$AR$3:$AR,Contacts!$AZ$3:$AZ,Contacts!$BH$3:$BH,Contacts!$BP$3:$BP,Contacts!$BX$3:$BX,Contacts!$CF$3:$CF,Contacts!$CN$3:$CN,Contacts!$CV$3:$CV,Contacts!$DD$3:$DD,Contacts!$DL$3:$DL,Contacts!$DT$3:$DT,Contacts!$EB$3:$EB,Contacts!$EJ$3:$EJ,Contacts!$ER$3:$ER,Contacts!$EZ$3:$EZ,Contacts!$FH$3:$FH,Contacts!$FP$3:$FP }, 
  "Leads",
  { Contacts!$U$3:$U,Contacts!$AC$3:$AC,Contacts!$AK$3:$AK,Contacts!$AS$3:$AS,Contacts!$BA$3:$BA,Contacts!$BI$3:$BI,Contacts!$BQ$3:$BQ,Contacts!$BY$3:$BY,Contacts!$CG$3:$CG,Contacts!$CO$3:$CO,Contacts!$CW$3:$CW,Contacts!$DE$3:$DE,Contacts!$DM$3:$DM,Contacts!$DU$3:$DU,Contacts!$EC$3:$EC,Contacts!$EK$3:$EK,Contacts!$ES$3:$ES,Contacts!$FA$3:$FA,Contacts!$FI$3:$FI,Contacts!$FQ$3:$FQ },
  "Shaun"
)
```

As you can see it's very long and would be difficult to correct or spot errors, even make alterations if necessary.

I wanted to name the ranges but don't know how to name an array. Then I thought about app script. Perhaps there was a way to create an array named range using app script, or even recreate the `countif` in app script?

Any Feedback is welcome, as always. 
I look forward to hearing/reading from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

any reason why not use this:

```
=COUNTIFS(
 QUERY(Contacts!$A$3:$FO, "select S,AA,AI,AQ,AY,BG,BO, BW ,CE,CM,CU,DC,DK,DS,EA,EI,EQ,EY,FG,FO", 0), 2,
 QUERY(Contacts!$A$3:$FN, "select R,Z ,AH,AP,AX,BF,BN, BV ,CD,CL,CT,DB,DJ,DR,DZ,EH,EP,EX,FF,FN", 0), $A19,
 QUERY(Contacts!$A$3:$FP, "select T,AB,AJ,AR,AZ,BH,BP, BX ,CF,CN,CV,DD,DL,DT,EB,EJ,ER,EZ,FH,FP", 0), "Leads",
 QUERY(Contacts!$A$3:$FQ, "select U,AC,AK,AS,BA,BI,BQ,`BY`,CG,CO,CW,DE,DM,DU,EC,EK,ES,FA,FI,FQ", 0), "Shaun")
```

[image]

Comment: To be honest, I just haven't thought about laying it out that way. That's a little bit better to look at and use. Thank you.

Comment: The way you set it out works perfectly! Thank you so much!
I just noticed the for the BY in the last QUERY, you added these little acute accents ( ` ) was there a reason for that? 

Also I added in one extra QUERY which I forgot to include in the original one, (using your method of course) and for some reason it doesn't count correctly.

Comment: Nevermind. I found my mistake, it was silly.
THANK YOU SO MUCH! You've been a great help!! :D

Comment: yup, BY column is kinda special when used in query so it needs to have those "little acute accents". its because of differentiation between column BY and command BY used in for example in "order by"